# IT Security Stack Exchange Site not available - DNS lookup failed?

Tags: bug

Is there a problem with http://security.stackexchange.com at the moment? Browsing from UK. The DNS lookup appears to fail. Tried OpenDNS and Google DNS servers and various online tools, but all return a blank?

Comment: A lot more is failing. Programmers is gone too at the moment.

Comment: @psubsee2003: This has gone beyond the metas..

Comment: Ah: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/454695422792335360

Comment: @MartijnPieters fair point, but seems to be the same problem.  We don't need a dozen questions on the same issue.

Comment: @psubsee2003: it's a new one, I think.

Comment: Yes, that Tweet was literally 2 mins ago. I had searched the questions, but found nothing relevant. Ultimately it is the same problem though... DNS (which is being resolved it seems).

Comment: @w3d: the DNS for Programmers and Security is back up, but not yet for the metas.